# Unable to use my android emulator, although it had been working fine for quite some time

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

This error appears everytime I try to open up my emulators. Currently I am using both of these emulators:

- Pixel 3a API 30
- Pixel 6 API 33

```
INFO | Android emulator version 32.1.11.0 (build_id 9536276) (CL:N/A) INFO | Found systemPath C:\Users\soham\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-33\google_apis\x86_64\ WARNING | Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\soham\.android\avd\Pixel_6_API_33.avd\quickbootChoice.ini for reading.
```

I tried to create another device, still to no use. Also updated the Project Structure, but got the same error.